# Distributed database synchronization

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, distributed-database

I am trying to understand  at a conceptual level , how are databases synchronized when they are largely distributed. eg a rail/airline reservation system. Do each of the market leaders have their own proprietary solution to handle this scenario?

Are they all locally present and each transaction is checked against a master copy?

I have worked with fail over databases which are locally present, i.e. master-slave scenario where on takes over when the other fails; but how are database which require real time transaction ability synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has a good article on the [Airline Reservation System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_Reservation_System). Quite a few references.

Answer (score -1):

Lots of distributed applications don't need to be 100% consistent all the time. Here's an article by Amazon's Werner Vogels on the subject:

http://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2008/12/eventually_consistent.html

Comment: The questioner clearly cites examples of distributed systems which *do* need to be synchronized in real time: ticket reservation systems.  Eventual consistency is not an appropriate solution for such applications.